exercise3.12 from Paolo Baldi's Stochastic Calculus
3.12 (p.463) Let $B=\left(\Omega, \mathscr{F},\left(\mathscr{F}_t\right)_t,\left(B_t\right)_t, \mathrm{P}\right)$ be a Brownian motion and let
$$
Z_t=B_t-\int_0^t \frac{B_u}{u} d u
$$
a) Note that the integral converges for almost every $\omega$ and show that $\left(Z_t\right)_t$ is a Brownian motion with respect to its natural filtration $\left(\mathscr{G}_t\right)_t$.
b) Show that $\left(Z_t\right)_t$ is a process adapted to the filtration $\left(\mathscr{F}_t\right)_t$, but it is not a Brownian motion with respect to this filtration.
c) Prove that, for every $t, B_t$ is independent of $\mathscr{G}_t$.

He used the conclusion of Exercise 3.11:

3.11 (p.461) Let $X$ be a continuous Gaussian process.
a) Let us denote by $G$ the family of the compactly supported finite measures $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$(i.e. such that $\gamma\left([a, b]^c\right)=0$ for some $\left.a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\right)$. Let
$$
X_\gamma=\int X_s d \gamma(s)
$$
Show that $\left(X_\gamma\right)_{\gamma \in G}$ is a Gaussian family.
b) Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$such that $\mu([a, b])<+\infty$ for every finite interval $[a, b]$ (i.e. a Borel measure) and let
$$
Y_t=\int_0^t X_s \mu(d s)
$$
b1) Prove that $Y$ is a Gaussian process.
b2)...

The solution he gave:

a) The integral that appears in the definition of $Z_t$ is convergent for almost every $\omega$ as, by the Iterated Logarithm Law, with probability 1, $\left|B_t\right| \leq$ $\left((2+\varepsilon) t \log \log \frac{1}{t}\right)^{1 / 2}$ for $t$ in a neighborhood of 0 and the function $t \mapsto$ $t^{-1 / 2}\left(\log \log \frac{1}{t}\right)^{1 / 2}$ is integrable at $0+$. Let us prove that $Z$ is a Gaussian process, i.e. that, for every choice of $t_1, \ldots, t_m$, the r.v. $\widetilde{Z}=\left(Z_{t_1}, \ldots, Z_{t_m}\right)$ is Gaussian. We cannot apply Exercise 3.11 b ) immediately because $\frac{1}{u} d u$ is not a Borel measure (it gives infinite mass to every interval containing 0). But, by Exercise 3.11 a), the r.v. $\widetilde{Z}^{(n)}=\left(Z_{t_1}^{(n)}, \ldots, Z_{t_m}^{(n)}\right)$ is indeed Gaussian, where $Z_{t_i}^{(n)}=0$ if $t_i<\frac{1}{n}$ and
$$
Z_{t_i}^{(n)}=B_{t_i}-\int_{1 / n}^{t_i} \frac{B_u}{u} d u \quad i=1, \ldots, m
$$
otherwise. Then just observe that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \widetilde{Z}^{(n)}=\widetilde{Z}$ a.s. and that a.s. convergence implies convergence in law. We deduce that $\widetilde{Z}$ is Gaussian, by Proposition 1.9.

Is the part I bolded an obvious conclusion? I don’t know how to use the conclusion of exercise3.11, because different t_i will form different Gaussian families.

